# Cannot execute list functions on a list of lists of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

This code was working fine until last night. It reads in a list of lists of data frames from Yahoo Finance. Each element in the list is a list with 2 dataframes, one for call options and another for put options, and each element is labeled by the expiration date of the options. The columns with dates in the dataframes are in a numeric format so I need to format those columns which is done in the last line of code but for some reason no longer works.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

urlExp <- "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AMZN"
tbl <- jsonlite::fromJSON(urlExp)
all.expiries.int <- tbl$optionChain$result$expirationDates[[1]]
all.expires.dates <- .POSIXct(as.numeric(all.expiries.int), tz="UTC")
urlExp <- paste0(urlExp, "?&date=", all.expiries.int)
  
option.chain <- lapply(urlExp,function(tick){
  tbl_exp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tick)
  
  dftables <- lapply(tbl_exp$optionChain$result$options[[1]][,c("calls","puts")], `[[`, 1L)
  
  dftables <- lapply(dftables,function(df) df %>% mutate(expiration = .POSIXct(as.numeric(expiration), tz="UTC"),lastTradeDate = .POSIXct(as.numeric(lastTradeDate), tz="UTC")))
})
```

When I run the code above I get this error:

`Error in UseMethod("mutate_") :  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"`

I have no idea why this error is coming up when I am not using "mutate_()" but I am using "mutate()".

I tried to rewrite the last line as:

```
dftables <- lapply(dftables,function(df) lapply(df, function(ddf) ddf %>% mutate(expiration = .POSIXct(as.numeric(expiration), tz="UTC"),lastTradeDate = .POSIXct(as.numeric(lastTradeDate), tz="UTC")))
```

But the error comes back as

`Error in UseMethod("mutate_") :  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Please show structure of json object: `str(tbl_exp)`.

Comment: I think you have missed a `}` in your initial code

Comment: @ChrissPaul you are correct. Just fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code fails for `urlExp[17]`, it does not have data for "puts". You can try this option with `tryCatch`.

```
library(dplyr)

option.chain <- lapply(urlExp,function(tick){
  tbl_exp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tick)
  dftables <- lapply(tbl_exp$optionChain$result$options[[1]][,c("calls","puts")], `[[`, 1L)
  
  dftables <- lapply(dftables,function(df) {
    tryCatch({
      df %>% 
        mutate(expiration = .POSIXct(as.numeric(expiration), tz="UTC"),
               lastTradeDate = .POSIXct(as.numeric(lastTradeDate), tz="UTC"))
    }, error = function(e) data.frame(val = NA))
  })
})
```

Comment: Something else to what already pointe out by @Ronak, there are some cases where column `expiration` is not available.